# Batch function not working correctly

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

A while ago I made a function that you can call from the command prompt or any batch file (it was just for fun, I don't see how it could be useful). It basically just makes your (Microsoft) computer speak whatever you wrote in as the parameter. 
I recently got some inspiration to add a switch to it where it would read the contents of a file. My standalone script worked, but when I added it to my function, it didn't work as I would have liked.

Here's the code:

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if "%~1"=="/?" (
    echo.
    echo TALK "Text" [Parameters]
    echo.
    echo Text - The phrase you want to be spoken.
    echo.
    echo [Parameters]:
    echo              /f - Read the contents of a file. "Text" changes to the file path.
    echo.
    endlocal
    exit /b
)

if "%~2 X" equ "/f X" (

    if not exist %~1 (
        echo File does not exist or cannot be found.
        endlocal
        exit /b
    )

    set cont= 
    for /f "delims=" %%i in (%~1) do set cont=!cont! %%i
    :b
    echo Set a = Wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice") > "Talk.vbs"
    echo a.speak "%cont%" >> "Talk.vbs"
    start /WAIT Talk.vbs
    del Talk.vbs
    endlocal
    exit /b
)

set text=%~1

echo set speech = Wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.spVoice") > "talk.vbs"
echo speech.speak "%text%" >> "talk.vbs"
start /WAIT talk.vbs
del Talk.vbs
endlocal
exit /b
```

Unfortunately I don't have working function code (before I added the `/f` switch).

This is a last resort for me as I've edited it heavily and scoured the code for any give away as to what the problem might be.

Another bad thing is that I didn't take note of what I changed, so I can't exactly tell you what I've tried. I can tell you what the outputs are though.

The first time I tried, it gave the output `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

It's now at the point where the original function (just converting text to speech) doesn't work anymore. The contents of the file `Talk.vbs` (which was made during the process) is `a.speak ""`.

I'll keep updating my attempts, but knowing me it's something really simple that I've overlooked.

--EDIT--
At the suggestion of someone, I put carats before the square brackets in the syntax section. Nothing changed.

Comment: The unquoted `%~1` entries may be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with escaping the parenthesis you also had to surround `if exist %~1` in quotes in case of a argument of `"some words I want it to say"`.  Also cleaned it up a bit.  Code at the bottom, but first an explanation.

If you looked at talk.vbs before it was deleted you would see this:

```
a.speak "!cont! contents of the file here"
```

This is because of this code:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (%~1) do set cont=!cont! %%i
:b
echo Set a = Wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice") > "Talk.vbs"
```

If you turned echo on and watched the code you would see the last unescaped `)` was taking the contents of the for loop and including it in the redirect.

Corrected and cleaned code:

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if "%~1"=="/?" (
    echo.
    echo TALK "Text" [Parameters]
    echo.
    echo Text - The phrase you want to be spoken.
    echo.
    echo [Parameters]:
    echo              /f - Read the contents of a file. "Text" changes to the file path.
    echo.
    endlocal
    exit /b
)
set text=
if [%2]==[/f] (
    if exist "%~1" (
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (%1) do set text=!text! %%i
    ) else (
        endlocal
        exit /B
    )
)
if [%2]==[] set text=%~1

echo set speech = Wscript.CreateObject^("SAPI.spVoice"^) > "talk.vbs"
echo speech.speak "%text%" >> "talk.vbs"
cscript //NoLogo //B talk.vbs
del Talk.vbs
endlocal
exit /b
```

**Edit:** fixed the `for` statement pointed out by Andriy M

Comment: One more unquoted `%~1` is in the `for /f` loop. You'll probably need to add `usebackq` to the options for the double quotes around `%~1` to be treated as file name delimiters and not as string delimiters.

Comment: Just wondering, is there any advantages in using the cscript command rather than just starting it?

Answer (score 1):

In your echo statements that contain parentheses, try escaping the parentheses with carats.  I suspect especially the echo within the if statement is partially getting evaluated literally.

One other minor suggestion, I would also replace

```
start /WAIT Talk.vbs
```

with

```
cscript /nologo Talk.vbs
```

It's not that I think the `start /wait` is causing the error, but it does cause a second console window to appear temporarily for no good reason -- or it will whenever your script executes that far, anyway.

I made a few other suggested changes here, such as eliminating the need for a /f switch.  If "%1" is the name of a file that exists, read it.  Otherwise, treat it as text to read.  And instead of having a separate subroutine for reading a file versus getting text from input, all that needs to happen is a variable has a different value.

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if "%1"=="/?" ( goto usage )
if "%1"=="" ( goto usage )
if "%1"=="--help" ( goto usage )
if exist "%1" (
    set txt=
    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (%1) do set txt=!txt! %%i
) else (
    set txt=%1
)
echo Set a = Wscript.CreateObject^("SAPI.SpVoice"^) > "talk.vbs"
echo a.speak "%txt%" >> "talk.vbs"
cscript /nologo talk.vbs
del talk.vbs
endlocal
goto :EOF

:usage
echo.
echo TALK ["text"^|filename]
echo.
echo talk filename -- speaks the contents of filename
echo talk "text"   -- speaks the supplied text
endlocal
goto :EOF
```

Comment: By parenthesis you mean the square brackets, right? I tried it and there is no difference.

Comment: No he means parenthesis.  Example `echo Set a = Wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice") > "Talk.vbs"` needs to be `echo Set a = Wscript.CreateObject^("SAPI.SpVoice"^) > "Talk.vbs"`

Comment: Right.  As the code is shown in your question above, the `)` is ending your `if` statement 6 lines earlier than you intended, resulting in that error message.

Comment: Well thanks. I chose Patrick Meinecke's answer over yours because he kept the nearly the same format as my original code, but yours is equally useful.