# Unable to stream content to file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I made this code that does the following:

1. Check if the word YouTube is in the computer's HOSTS file
2. If not - insert the word YouTube into the file
3. If there is - delete the word YouTube from the file. And operates a timer for the return of the word YouTube
   After each process - stop the Chrome.exe task
   For some reason it does not work.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(reg query "HKU\S-1-5-19" || (powershell start-process -FilePath '%0' -verb runas&exit /B)) >NUL 2>&1
:start
FIND /i "www.youtube.com" "%WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts" >nul 2>&1 
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo.
    echo 127.0.0.1 www.youtube.com >> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    Taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe
)  ELSE (
    set /p "OPEN_TIME=Enter time: "
    echo.
    echo # Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo #>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo # This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo #>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo # This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo # entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo # be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo # The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo # space.>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo #>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo # Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo # lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo #>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo # For example:>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo #>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo #      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo #       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo: >> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo #  127.0.0.1       localhost>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo #  ::1             localhost>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo 127.0.0.1 view-localhost # view localhost server>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    Taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe
    timeout /T !OPEN_TIME!
    GOTO start
)
```

If I delete the whole ELSE command and leave only this code it does work:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(reg query "HKU\S-1-5-19" || (powershell start-process -FilePath '%0' -verb runas&exit /B)) >NUL 2>&1
:start
FIND /i "www.youtube.com" "%WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts" >nul 2>&1 
if errorlevel 1 (
   echo.
   echo 127.0.0.1 www.youtube.com >> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
   Taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe
)
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: __"For some reason it does not work."__ That is an extremely broad statement to a porblem. Please clarify what _"does not work"_ mean. What happens/Does not happen and what have you done to debug your own issue? Hint, remove `@echo off` to help you debug.

Comment: You closed the `ELSE` every time you use a closing parentheses.  If you need to echo a closing parentheses you must escape it. `^)`

Comment: The window immediately closes without performing any action.

Comment: Therefore also will not help to delete the echo off

Comment: First rule of debugging a batch file. Execute the batch file from the command prompt instead of using your mouse. Second rule is don't use ECHO OFF or change it to ECHO ON so that you can see the code execute.

Comment: I explain that this is the problem - the window opens for a second and closes and does not help to delete the echo off

Comment: @אוריהדניאלי Becaus you are double clicking the file. Open `cmd` then `cd` to the path where the file is, then run it from there. It will not exit then.

Comment: That I run the code with the help of cmd it gives me an error message on this line `echo # Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts`
`1993-2009 was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: Yes, because of what @Squashman told you higher up. You need to escape all the closing parenthesis in your echo commands as each one encountered will be seen as the closing parenthesis of the else statement. you escape them as `^)`

Comment: Reading is FUN. If you can't comprehend the information someone has given you then please ask for further clarification before continuing on.  Otherwise we all are repeating what we said and are wasting everyone's time.

Comment: You can show on the code the change needed - I did not quite understand the comment. (I do not speak English and use Google Translate ...)

Comment: How am I supposed to write the parentheses at the end?

Comment: See also this thread: [Batch function not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14793998)

Comment: If you're going to mess with the `hosts` file, and its access isn't restricted by security software or policies, then it would make more sense if you designed your script to toggle the entry, using the `#` comment. That way, you should only need to add or remove the comment instead of rewriting entire lines. In order to do this however, I'd suggest that you use a different scripting language, one which can safely replace strings directly, instead of using a holding file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The E-Z way of making the lines write-able is to just be out of the outer parenthesis of the IF.

This is simple to accomplish by shuffling the whole lot of the insides of the IF into a called function, this also make sit fairly straight forward to test and the code may be easier to follow.

I want to note that because you are replacing the file contents with your own, you can never be sure you aren't over-writing any other entries added by yourself or other programs (for instance, anti-malware is known to put in many!)

You could adjust for this by writing a copy of the hosts with all existing lines in it except those you wish to remove, and your additional line added, then moving it replacing the normal hosts file in the process.

**however, for now, lets just take your code and make it a little easier to handle.**

Also, I think you want to loop every 30 minutes regardless of whether the item is found, no?  you seem to be saying the code should always loop.  I moved that for this reason.

Make sure you are running this form the command line to test it instead of by double clicking it.

Also, make sure that the command prompt is running as administrator as you may not be able to make changes to the hosts file if it isn't.

```cmd
@(setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  echo off
  (reg query "HKU\S-1-5-19" || (powershell start-process -FilePath '%0' -verb runas&exit /B)) >NUL 2>&1
  SET "Write-Hosts=CALL :Write_Hosts "
  SET "_HostsFilePath=%WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts"
)

CALL :Main

( ENDLOCAL
  Exit /b
)

:Main
  FIND /i "www.youtube.com" "%_HostsFilePath%" >nul 2>&1 
  if errorlevel 1 (
    CALL :Missing
  )  ELSE (
    CALL :Found
  )
  Taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe
  FOR /F "Tokens=2-3 delims=:." %%A IN ("%TIME%") DO (SET /A "Timer=(30-((1%%A-(2%%A-1%%A))%%30))*60 - (1%%B-(2%%B-1%%B))")
  Echo.Waiting %OPEN_TIME% Seconds before Running again.
  timeout /T %OPEN_TIME%
 GOTO :Main
GOTO :EOF

:Missing
  echo. Adding 127.0.0.1 www.youtube.com
  %Write-Hosts%127.0.0.1 www.youtube.com
GOTO :EOF

:Found
  REM set /p "OPEN_TIME=Enter time: "
  REM echo.
  echo. Resetting Hosts
  SET "Output=>"
  %Write-Hosts%# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
  %Write-Hosts%#
  %Write-Hosts%# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
  %Write-Hosts%#
  %Write-Hosts%# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
  %Write-Hosts%# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
  %Write-Hosts%# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
  %Write-Hosts%# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
  %Write-Hosts%# space.
  %Write-Hosts%#
  %Write-Hosts%# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
  %Write-Hosts%# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
  %Write-Hosts%#
  %Write-Hosts%# For example:
  %Write-Hosts%#
  %Write-Hosts%#     102.54.94.97    rhino.acme.com        # source server
  %Write-Hosts%#      38.25.63.10    x.acme.com            # x client host
  %Write-Hosts%# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
  %Write-Hosts%#  127.0.0.1      localhost
  %Write-Hosts%#  ::1           localhost
  %Write-Hosts% 127.0.0.1 view-localhost # view localhost server
GOTO :EOF

:Write_Hosts
  ECHO.%*
  ECHO.%*%Output% "%_HostsFilePath%"
  SET "Output=>>"
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fixed version of the code:
Note I changed NOTHING other than `Copyright (c^)` and `comments (such as these^)`

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(reg query "HKU\S-1-5-19" || (powershell start-process -FilePath '%0' -verb runas&exit /B)) >NUL 2>&1
:start
FIND /i "www.youtube.com" "%WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts" >nul 2>&1 
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo.
    echo 127.0.0.1 www.youtube.com >> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    Taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe
)  ELSE (
    set /p "OPEN_TIME=Enter time: "
    echo.
    echo # Copyright (c^) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo #>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo # This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo #>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo # This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo # entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo # be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo # The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo # space.>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo #>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo # Additionally, comments (such as these^) may be inserted on individual>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo # lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo #>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo # For example:>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo #>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo #      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo #       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo: >> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo #  127.0.0.1       localhost>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo #  ::1             localhost>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    echo 127.0.0.1 view-localhost # view localhost server>> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts
    Taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe
    timeout /T !OPEN_TIME!
    GOTO start
)
```